# Converting currency to format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, concat-ws

I want to combine two numbers (monthly net/monthly gross) and edit their formats. for example; 784.453,14

The code I wrote is as follows;

```
concat_ws('/'::text, 
          btrim(to_char(ks.aylik_kira, '9G999G999G999D00'::text)),   
          btrim(to_char(ks.aylik_kira_brut, '9G999G999G999D00'::text))
) AS aylik_net_brut,
```

but I'm getting an error and it's not working. How can I do that?

the result should be like this: `147.422,12/148.587,5`

Comment: I personally would rather just request the data from the database and leave formatting to the application.

Comment: Please share the error message, we don't have access to your machine and we can't see it

Comment: https://r.resimlink.com/mpfiO75V.jpg

Comment: i added error message to the link

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete and exact error message you get as text - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: Unrelated, but: `'/'::text` can be simplified to `'/'` - the other casts are also not needed.

Comment: thank you but there is no answer to my question :(

Comment: Well, there is no complete question (the data and the error message are missing).

Comment: actually i will cry :'/

Comment: The btrim function is used to remove whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string, but it's being applied to the output of to_char, which returns a formatted string. can you try this   concat_ws('/'::text, 
          to_char(ks.aylik_kira, '999G999G999D00'::text),   
          to_char(ks.aylik_kira_brut, '999G999G999D00'::text)
) AS aylik_net_brut

Comment: unfortunately it didn't, i was so hopeful :(

Comment: Simple as I could get given information provided:   `select trim(to_char(147422.12, '9G999G999G999D00')) || '/' || trim(to_char(148587.5, '9G999G999G999D00')) ; 147.422,12/148.587,50`